# Is there an easy way to remove black background from the PNG?

Tags: javascript, css, background, png

I have a PNG image:
[image]

I need to remove the black corners and make them transparent.
I have found a way to do it. What it does:
Create a canvas, then edit the PNG pixel by pixel and change totally black to transparent. And eventually I get base64 image with transparent background.
It works, but the procedure is awful.
Is the a fast and easy way?
Maybe something like using CSS filters?

```js
const toDataURL = (src: string) => {   
    const img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = () => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
      // @ts-expect-error
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');      
      // @ts-expect-error
      canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
      // @ts-expect-error      
      canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

      // This part will remove the black background
      // @ts-expect-error
      const imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
      const data=imgData.data;

      for(let i=3; i < data.length; i+=4){ 
        if (data[i-1] === 0 && data[i-2] === 0 && data[i-3] === 0 && data[i] === 255) {
          data[i] = 0;
        }
      }
      ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

      // This will get us the base64 string
      // @ts-expect-error
      const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

      setTestUrl(dataURL);
    };
    img.src = src;

    // if (img.complete || img.complete === undefined) {
    //   img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==';
    //   img.src = src;
    // }
  };
  
  toDataURL(
    // randomPngImage,
    PNG_TEST,
    // JPG doesn't work
    // JPG_TEST,
  );
```

Comment: What's wrong with current solution? Looks good to me

Comment: But I need to go pixel by pixel.
Millions of iterations for every image.
Doesn't sound very nice.